# python:window with no title bar, and change window default color(grey) to black

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I wrote a code to pop up a window on my screen and to print a data on the window.Here according to my requirement i want the entire screen to be BLACK in color. SO that i can print some text on that black window. The window title bar tkinter should be removed and the entire window screen should be in black.

Comment: self.wm_overrideredirect(True)  # to remove the title bar.          but some one help me to change my background color to black.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `self.configure(background='black')` or `self['bg'] = 'black'`. Most Tkinter widgets can be configured with similar properties.

Answer (score 1):

Just do:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title('')
root.config(background='black')

root.mainloop()
```

And that should work!